# Generate a random variable which follow Gamma distribution and AR(1) process simulatenously

Tags: random-generation, autoregressive

Is it possible to generate numbers from Gamma distribution (with parameters shape=10, scale=15, say) which also follow a AR(1) process, simultaneously? If it's possible, than how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this sort of thing will generally be possible without changing some aspects of the usual definition of an AR.

[most of original answer removed, since I have better information]

---

Richard Hardy points out in the comments below that probably meant a Gamma marginal distribution (... and rereading your question, that makes sense); Richard thought to use an innovation-approach to create the model. While it's not possible to pick just any distribution for innovations, there is at least one such innvation-model that does work (see the Lawrance reference below).

Here's some references that will prove useful:

Grunwald G.K., Hyndman R.J., Tedesco, L. and Tweedie, R. L. (2000)
"Non-Gaussian Conditional Linear AR(1) Models,"
Australian & New Zealand Journal of Statistics, **42**:4 (Dec) p479-495
DOI: 10.1111/1467-842X.00143
(Working paper here: http://robjhyndman.com/papers/clar.pdf)

This and the research report below discuss a variety of approaches to non-Gaussian AR(1) models. [The above paper gives a general formulation of non-Gaussian AR(1) models that includes nearly all published non-Gaussian AR(1) models, while the report below is partly a survey paper as well as beginning
the synthesis of the paper above.]

Grunwald, G.K., Hyndman, R.J. and Tedesco, L.M. (1995),
"A unified view of linear AR(1) models,"
Research Report, Department of Statistics, University of Melbourne
(http://robjhyndman.com/papers/ar1.pdf)

Lawrance, A.J. (1982),
"The innovation distribution of a gamma distributed autoregressive process,"
Scand. J. Statist., **9**, 234–236

---

[You could perhaps more readily construct an AR in the log of a gamma. Fitted to log-data, that would correspond to a shifting scale in the conditional distribution for the gamma.]

Comment: The $\varepsilon_t$ does not belong in the formula since its expectation is zero. Also, could you elaborate a little on *how* an AR(1) process seems to imply a need for a location-family?

Comment: @Richard Thanks for pointing out the epsilon. The effect of the previous observation shifts the mean linearly with $y_{t-1}$ but leaves the conditional variance unaltered. Under the condition that one also wants to have a particular distribution family (as was asked for in the question,  which to begin with I interpreted as a requirement on the conditional distribution) the need to be able to shift the mean without changing the variance withing a distribution family suggests a location family for that conditional distribution (which would only change the location).

Comment: Similar, but slightly different issues arise if we try to deal with the unconditional distribution being gamma.

Comment: I thought the *unconditional* distribution had to be gamma, and I was interested how one could reject this intuitively, i.e. intuitively motivate why outcomes of AR(1) could not be unconditionally Gamma-distributed..

Comment: @Richard Hmm. Are you anticipating that the shape of the conditional distribution changes from observation to observation in order to end up with a Gamma? (without that, there's a pretty obvious problem)

Comment: I thought maybe an AR(1) process with a fixed error distribution (thus it is always Normal or always Student or always something else) can give an unconditional Gamma distribution. I might very well be wrong, but I wonder what an intuitive reason could be for rejecting this possibility.

Comment: @Richard We can certainly reject both of those because they give nonzero probabilities of a negative observation. which can't then be gamma. Similarly if we restrict ourselves to a distribution that's bounded on the left, we still have problems (e.g. because of the various ways negatives can still arise) unless you make the distribution change.

Comment: @RIchardHardy I've added some references; the specific one by Lawrance seems to addresses the particular approach you were envisioning, where in that case the innovation has a compound Poisson distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much  for the answer and the references. It helped me to understand the issue more clearly.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, thanks a lot for this answer, and these two papers that you cited; they gave me a new perspective to think about AR processes as a process characterized by conditional and marginal distributions—just super nice! 

Though, can you elaborate your latter remark on the log of gamma and constructing AR(1) on log of the data?

I want to use GAR(1) (of Gaver and Lewis, 1980; Lawrance 1982) to generate, date and my supervisors find it too complicated.