# Simulate an AR(1) process that approximates gamma-like distribution

Tags: time-series, simulation, autoregressive

I’d like to simulate an AR(1) time series that *approximates* a gamma distribution rather than a normal distribution. I’d like the result to have a specified rate and shape along with a AR(1) process with a given `phi`. I have seen this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180109/generate-a-random-variable-which-follow-gamma-distribution-and-ar1-process-sim) and understand that a strict gamma simulation is problematic, but I'd be satisfied with a result that approximates the shape and rate. Some crude adjustment of `shape` and `rate` as a function of `phi` is likely enough for my needs. Any idea?

E.g.,

```
n <- 500
foo <- rgamma(n = n, shape = 1.5 , rate = 5)

phi <- 0.3
bar <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = phi), n = n, 
                 rand.gen = rgamma, shape = 1.5,
                 rate = 5)

ggplot() + 
  geom_density(aes(x=foo),fill="#FF8C00",alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=bar),fill="#A034F0",alpha=0.5)
```